# Run the entire selected code at the same time?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Currently if I have two lines (or more) of code selected, hitting `Run Selection`, will execute the selected lines one by one in the terminal:
[image]

I want to execute all lines of code at one time, like a single "script", this is how it works everywhere else.

I have been trying to solve this all day, I thought this would be a straight forward settings to figure out but no. I cant find any setting in the `defualtSettings.json` for this issue.

and all my online searching just lead me to "multiline line editing". I thought this would be a common issue many encountered but I cant find anything.

Is there a way to execute the entire selection at once?

Comment: I suspect that only works with the integrated terminal

Comment: What do you mean with execution at once? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @DavidTrevor they mean multiple lines as part of the same commandline. I've found related issue tickets and asked the maintainers of the powershell extension for more info. waiting on their response to write an answer post.